# Mysql - Search for a multi-word query

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I'm trying to return results from a table of products when a user searches it by name. Currently I have this query (simplified):

```
SELECT id, name FROM products WHERE status > 0 AND MATCH(name) AGAINST('test druzy%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0, 50
```

Where my search query was `test druzy`. These are the results I get.

[image: results of first query]

The problem is that I don't want results 'Test Tie Necklace' for instance. Mysql is searching for **test** and **druzy** seperately. How do I search for both words combined. Performance is also a concern since the table is expected to be very large.

I tried using LIKE as well but that doesn't return any results at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To search for both words you could use `+` operator like

```
MATCH(name) AGAINST('+test +druzy' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/RMYDEU25944)

[Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried lower the field name and apply LIKE like this :

```
SELECT id, name
FROM products
WHERE status > 0
AND LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('Test Druzy%')
ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0, 50
```

EDIT : You can put LOWER at the other side
Or use a charset format case-insensitive

Comment: Interesting. That does return the results. Is there a way to make LIKE case-insensitive? The user might enter 'Test Druzy' as well. If not, I guess I can lower both sides too compare.

Comment: `LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('Test Druzy%')` stops the use off a index.. Unless you use generated columns and index those.. "That does return the results. Is there a way to make LIKE case-insensitive?" The most simple solution would be to use a case-insensitive charset.. @VeeK

Comment: Thanks for the index thing. I can use PHP to convert the string into lowercase and then use it in te original query A. Colonna wrote. I guess gets around that problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using MATCH query you should use LIKE query.